# jQuery breaking in Firefox but no other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following code which works fine in all browsers including Firefox:

```
var top;
var imageHeight;
function upFunction() {
    top = parseInt($(".feature img").css("top"));
    imageHeight = $(".feature img").height();
    if (top > (imageHeight - 335) * -1) {
        $(".feature img").css("top", top - 1 + "px");
        $("#topPos").val(top - 1);
    }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a#up").mousedown( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        upFunction();
        timeoutId = setInterval( upFunction, 100 );
    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
    });
});
```

However there's obviously something else in my page which is causing this not to work in firefox and I can't work it out.

Is there any way I can fond out what's causing it to break without removing everything from the page to find out what it is?

EDIT:

OK, with the help of Jai's answer, it appears that a small tweak to my code makes it work in Firefox. Here's what I did:

```
function upFunction() {
    var top = parseInt($(".feature img").css("top"));
    var imageHeight = $(".feature img").height();
    if (top > (imageHeight - 335) * -1) {
        $(".feature img").css("top", top - 1 + "px");
        $("#topPos").val(top - 1);
    }
};
```

and remove the 2 variables from the global scope. Not sure why it made a different but it did.

Comment: Do you have Firebug, if yes, what's the error shown in the console? If not, get it and then see the error.

Comment: What exactly "breaking" means? Which part isn't working?

Comment: *"Is there any way I can fond out what's causing it to break without removing everything from the page to find out what it is?"* Yes, use FF's developer tools or Firebug, have a look at the console, set breakpoints, inspect variables... just normal JavaScript debugging.

Comment: In Firefox, you can open `Error Console` via `Tools` -> `Web Developer` -> `Error Console`. If some javascript error arises, it will show up here.

Comment: Why did you declare `top` and `imageHeight` in the global scope (you're using them only local) and didn't declare `timeoutId` at all? Likely, the other scripts on the page will interfere with them

Comment: `I have the following code which works fine in all browsers including Firefox:` and `something else in my page which is causing this not to work in firefox` can't get it????????????????

Comment: the error console does not show any error, that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible to help if you refuse to tell what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try these fixed variable declarations:

```
function upFunction() {
    var img = $(".feature img"),
        top = parseInt(img.css("top"));
    if (top > (335 - img.height())) {
        img.css("top", top - 1 + "px");
        $("#topPos").val(top - 1);
    }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeoutId;
    $("a#up").mousedown( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        upFunction();
        timeoutId = setInterval( upFunction, 100 );
    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
    });
});
```

On your actual question: Debug your script via inspecting it in the developer tools (Firebug).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one:

```
function upFunction(top, imageHeight) {
   if (top > (imageHeight - 335) * -1) {
       $(".feature img").css("top", top - 1 + "px");
       $("#topPos").val(top - 1);
   }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var top = parseInt($(".feature img").css("top"));
    var imageHeight = $(".feature img").height();
    $("a#up").mousedown( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        upFunction(top, imageHeight);
        timeoutId = setInterval(function(){
                        upFunction(top, imageHeight);
                    }, 100);
    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        clearInterval(timeoutId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `top` as a var name in global scope, it's already used.

Try typing `console.log(top)` or `alert(window.top)` into your browser's console for reference.